# Virtual Environment using old version of Python

Tags: python, pip, version, virtualenv

I'm running version 2.7.12 of python on my mac.
For a project I need that version exactly, and for some reason the version I got inside the venv is 2.7.10.

I have tried a lot, even reinstalling the virtual environment from scratch, but it will still use that version.

Is there something I can do to update the version inside the virtual env?

Comment: `virtualenv -p \`which python2.7.12\` <path/to/new/virtualenv>` might fix it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv

Comment: likely dupe of [Use different Python version with virtualenv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv)

Comment: no dupe, that suggests to use 2.7, but both are 2.7. that didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pyenv` to install other version of Python. See instructions on https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer:

```
curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yyuu/pyenv-installer/master/bin/pyenv-installer | bash
```

Follow the instructions to place the correct variables in your `~/.bash_profile`, like this

```
echo 'export PATH="/root/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Restart you terminal, and then

```
pyenv install 2.7.12
pyenv local 2.7.12
```

Now Python 2.7.12 is availabe as `python`.

Comment: I think the OP want 2.7.12